# Does the IMEI block also blocks the Find My Phone feature?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I followed a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94283/does-find-my-iphone-still-work-with-a-sim-block) about SIM blocking and still don't know whether I should request an IMEI block.

I spoke to a store and when I asked them about what happens if I give them the IMEI number and they block it completely, will the "wipe data" feature work from the Find My iPhone app?

The first person could not say, the second "Apple specialist" ensured me that this should not be a problem even though I explicit questioned this. And now after a bit of googling it seems like my suspicions were correct! It seems like the IMEI lock blocks everything ans also the signal from the iCloud to wipe the phone.

Can anybody confirm if this true or not?

Comment: The linked question is a bit fuzzy on what problem is being solved. Perhaps you could edit in the exact problem you face. (i.e. Phone with FMF is powered off. Then you block IMEI. then what? Do you expect the block to stop an erase or surveillance to that block to _not_ stop the erase/monitoring? Does your use case care about Wireless access?)